# Simulate Shift+Click in application that uses GetAsyncKeyState() C++ WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Is there a way to simulate a Shift+Click for an application that uses `GetAsyncKeyState` to get the state of the Shift button?   `SendInput`, `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` API-s do not work since they only send messages to the target window and `GetAsyncKeyState` checks directly for the state of keyboard keys. So, other than hooking `GetAsyncKeyState` to return appropriate value for the Shift key, what other route one can take?

Comment: `API-s do not work since they only send messages to the target window and GetAsyncKeyState checks directly for the state of keyboard keys` - not quite. Please see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773/. You probably need to simulate a long key press rather than an instantaneous keydown+keyup.

Comment: @GSerg I was under the impression that GetAsyncKeyState used another, 'closer to hardware' approach to get keyboard keys' states. However the official MSDN page on this API does not go much into details. I did however try setting a 500 millisecond delay between key_down and key_up messages but GetAsyncKeyState still doesn't detect the key press

Comment: `SendInput` doesn't have a `HWND` parameter. Neither a thread or even process ID. It doesn't send input **anywhere**. It injects it, and whichever thread was the foreground thread at that time receives the input. *"what other route one can take?"* - The standard route: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). I'm just going to subscribe the fact, that the target application were to use any particular API for input as a guess. You've been guessing about `SendInput`, so that may actually be justified.

Comment: The target application specifically uses GetAsyncKeyState to check the state of Ctrl and Shift keys. My assumption on SendInput comes from MSDN forums post, evidently wrong one.

Comment: `SendInput()` injects events in the same input queue that the actual keyboard driver posts its input events to, so `GetAsyncKeyState()` should be handling *ANY* kind of keyboard input just fine, whether it is typed by the user or injected by code.